# Decorator: Cannot access 'xxx' before initialization

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator

I am not sure how to resolve this, but I am getting an error that says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'game' before initialization

So, I tried making the properties and methods static but that didn't do anything. What can I do to add decorators to classes that add the item to my `registeredComponents` property within the `Game` class?

The libraries main entry point looks like this:

```
import { Game } from './Game'
export const game = new Game
```

The game component creates an instance of Transform and adds it to its internal list:

```
import { Transform } from './core/components/Transform'

export class Game {
  private registeredComponents: Set<typeof Behavior> = new Set<typeof Behavior>()

  public registerComponent(component: typeof Behavior): void {
    this.registeredComponents.add(component)
  }

  public instantiate() {
    const gameObject = new GameObject()
    const transform = new Transform(gameObject)
    // Do some other stuff
  }
}
```

Here I use my decorator on the Transform:

```
@Component()
export class Transform extends Behavior {
  public position: Vector3 = Vector3.zero
}
```

This is what the decorator looks like:

```
export function Component() {
  return (target: typeof Behavior): void => {
    game.registerComponent(target)
  }
}
```

### Usage

In another project that I am using to use this library, it looks like this:

```
import { game, PrefabUtil } from 'gameengine'

class Item extends PrefabUtil { }

game.instantiate(Item)
```

Comment: There is a circular dependency index -> game -> transform -> component -> game

Comment: That isn't a circular dependency unless game was exported in component which it is not.

Comment: It is. Your decorator uses an instance of Game. Game class uses Transform class that is decorated with the mentioned decorator. Decorator applies when the module is evaluated (at import time) not when you make an instance (`new Transform()`)

Comment: @Shlang, actually that is true but fine. As you say, the decorator is invoked when the module is evaluated but it's not the decorator that throws but rather the function it returns that throws.

Comment: `function Component` is not a decorator, it is a decorator factory (thus you need to add `()` when you apply it) and the function it returns is a real decorator that is called when the module is evaluated. Please check [this playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jyptrh)

Answer (score 1):

So... It looks like in order to do this, I need to use a dynamic `import()`. This will delay the call to the decorator until after the `Game` object is created.

```
export class Game {
  public async instantiate() {
    const Transform = (await import('./core/components/Transform')).Transform
    const transform = new Transform(gameObject)
  }
}
```

Removal of the following line is also necessary:

```
import { Transform } from './core/components/Transform'
```

Comment: It’s times like these when the flexibility of Javascript can be a negative. Your error is being caused by the circular dependency mentioned by @Shlang, and there being a circular dependency is an indicator that there’s problems in your architecture. You’ve found a hacky solution that makes it works how you want, but it’s probably going to cause you no end of grief later down the line. Please look again and see if you can structure the code in a different way to still achieve what you want without hacks, it’ll save you a lot of time and problems in the long run!